# Getting Unknown error (0x80005000) with Directory services in asp .net, IIS 8 environment

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, directoryservices, directorysearcher

Error is happening in the code shown here.

I tried the following based on google research, but still error persists

1. Ensured "LDAP" is in upper case
2. Installed II6 meatabase 6.

Error goes off if Application pool or IIS is restarted. But after a day, it comes back. any help is appreciated.

```
DE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://iaai.com/DC=iaai,DC=com");

AdSearch = new DirectorySearcher(DE);
AdSearch.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user) (sAMAccountName={0}))", sAcct);
AdSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userprincipalname");
AdResult = AdSearch.FindOne();
```

Comment: The fact that a pool reset and IIS reset resolve the issue for you are red flags for me. Is the machine running out of memory?

Comment: thanks. no, there is no issue of running out of memory. The servers are non prod and not used much. when i said iis reset ..it meant website restart.

Answer (score 1):

Error 0x80005000 may be caused by permission issues, Plus the parameters for the user name and password should be set to string or "Nothing" and not nothing.

```
DE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://iaai.com/DC=iaai,DC=com", userName, password);
```

Comment: if it is permission issue, it should never work. But in my case, it works when for a day or two and then it starts giving this error.  I assume in the absence of username and password, it will use the application pool user.

Comment: It's likely to be the user it's connecting to AD as. The App Pool is likely to be AppPoolIdentity, which is Anonymous user. Try changing the app pool identity to NetworkService and see if that works.